# Python - overriding function parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Writing a cli function that should do the following:

In case, the function parameters are not set (I get them from docopt),
I would like to look them up from environment.
The following does not work due to fast loading in functions:

```
def my_function(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    for v in ("a", "b", "c"):
        if vars()[v] is None:
            locals()[v] = getenv("env_{}".format(v).upper())
    do_something_with(a, b, c)
```

What would be the pythonic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with keyword arguments:

```
def my_function(**kwargs):
    for var in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        if kwargs.get(var) is None:
            kwargs[var] = getenv("env_{}".format(v).upper())
    do_something_with(**kwargs)
```

If you want to keep the signature, you can create a decorator (`functools.wraps` takes care of aligning the signatures):

```
def defaults_from_env(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        for var in kwargs:
            if kwargs.get(var) is None:
                kwargs[var] = getenv("env_{}".format(var).upper())
        return function(**kwargs)
    return wrapper


@defaults_from_env
def my_function(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    print(a, b, c)
```

However, this forces you to name all parameters when calling the decorated `my_function` (i.e. `a=.., b=.., c=..`). To avoid this, you could use [`inspect.signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object) to bind the parameters in the wrapper; this would allow you to get the name and value of all parameters, both `*arg` and `**kwarg`.

Comment: Thanks, thought about that. Unfortunately with kwargs I have no control over function params that are passed to the function and i would need to write:

1. a validator (to prevent parameters that are not allowed to be passed)
2. some extra parameter hinting for my ide,
3. I am not able to pass parameters by order